# Prepare to segue issue on ios

Tags: ios

I have declared on my.h file `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *newsArticle;`
On my.m i have the methods:

```
- (IBAction)synopsis:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%@?api_key=34eb86f3b94de2676e8d3007b5ce1993",movieid];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetcheMovie:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
    });
}

- (void)fetcheMovie:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    newsArticle= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"data1 = %@",newsArticle);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"data2 = %@",newsArticle);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"web"]){
        WebViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.imdbnumber=@"tt0105236rodrigo";
    }
}
```

On the fetcheMovie method I can get the values of newsArticle but I can't do the same on the prepareForSegue method.

What do I need to do in order to access these values? I need to access on value to pass to the next view
Thanks
Rodrigo

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call in your `- (void)fetcheMovie:(NSData *)responseData` or in the method where you want to push the next view controller, the following:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:newsArticle];
```

And in your `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` the sender will be the newsArticle sendet as param in `performSegue`

**EDIT**

```
- (void)fetcheMovie:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:json];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      NSDictionary *jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue = (NSDictionary*)sender;

      newsArticle= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
      WebViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
      vc.viewControllerProperty = newsArticle;
}
```

You have to change the property from your destination view controller accordingly. And you can change the variable names as you like.

Comment: Thanks danypata but can you show me how to structure the (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender, I am confused about the sender part been the "sendet as param in performSegue"

Comment: Thank, but I am getting an error, I guess because it is missing a closiing ")", I see it opens here 
NSDictionary *jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue = (NSDictionary*
but I don't see where it should be closed, can u tell me please

Comment: After putting the ) that is what I get:

assignment to cast is illegal . Ivalue casts are not supported

Comment: I got the error to go away, now when I click on my button that calls the methods, i get this:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[UIRoundedRectButton bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x95597a0'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29550/discussion-between-rodrigo-schreiner-and-danypata)

Comment: hey  danypata, can u go to the chat?